# Configure visual studio to publish handler mappings to IIS web application with one-click publish

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-2012

Every time I use the publish feature in ms visual studio my custom handler mappings become erased. I have some HttpHandler items that I need deployed on my IIS server. Is there a way to configure visual studio to publish all my handlers so I don't have to do it every time I publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was using a handler when really I needed a web service. I switched to web services and it now I don't need to do the handler mappings each time I deploy